# how to close/dismise dialog class from Activity in android?

Tags: android, dialog, dismiss, customdialog

I create `CustomDialog` with using `CustomDialogClass` for BackBTN as below:

```
    public void onBackPressed () {
    CustomDialogClass cdd = new CustomDialogClass(Adult1Activity.this);
    cdd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    cdd.show();
}


public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog {
    public Activity c;
    public Button minimizeBTN, exitBTN;

    public CustomDialogClass(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        this.c = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.back_btn);
        minimizeBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minimizing_app);
        exitBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_completely);

       ...

    }

    @Override
    public void dismiss() {
        super.dismiss();
        //cdd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Whenever I go back to the MainActivity, this dialog exists. So I want to close/dismise it from MainActivity class like `cdd.dismise;`. But unfortunately it does not happen. Would you please help me? Thanks

MainActivity.class:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public CustomDialogClass cdd; // back dialog
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    public String timeString;
    public NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private static final String EXTRA_NOTE = "NOTE";
    private static final String NOTE_RESTORE = "restore";
    private static final String NOTE_CLOSE = "close";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_adult1);

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    //alert dialog for back btn
    public void onBackPressed () {
        CustomDialogClass cdd = new CustomDialogClass(Adult1Activity.this);
        cdd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        cdd.show();
    }


    public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog {
        public Activity c;
        public Button minimizeBTN, exitBTN;

        public CustomDialogClass(Activity a) {
            super(a);
            this.c = a;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.back_btn);
            minimizeBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minimizing_app);
            exitBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_completely);

            minimizeBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    MinimizeApp();
                    isRunning = true;

                    ExtendedNotification(timeString);
                }
            });


            exitBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    CloseApp();
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void dismiss() {
            super.dismiss();
        }
    }

//*****************Notification class******
    private void ExtendedNotification(String time) {
        final Intent resultIntentRestore = new Intent(this, Adult1Activity.class);
        resultIntentRestore.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTE, NOTE_RESTORE);
        PendingIntent restoreIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Adult1Activity.this,
                0, resultIntentRestore, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        final Intent resultIntentClose = new Intent(this, Adult1Activity.class);
        resultIntentClose.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTE, NOTE_CLOSE);
        PendingIntent closeIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Adult1Activity.this,
                2, resultIntentClose, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

         final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Adult1Activity.this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("App Name")
                .setContentText(time)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Restore", restoreIntent))
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Close", closeIntent))
                .setContentIntent(restoreIntent);

         notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent); // Make sure to call super
        handleIntent(intent);
}

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        final String a = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_NOTE);
        if (a != null) {
            switch (a) {
                case NOTE_RESTORE:
                    tv.setText(timeString);
                    **cdd.dismiss();**

                    break;

                case NOTE_CLOSE:
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    isRunning = false;
                    notificationManager.cancel(0);
                    CloseApp();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to close/dismise `cdd` in `NOTE_RESTORE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the Dialog whenever you leave Activity, keep the dialog as a member, and dismiss it onStop()

```
// Keep track of the dialog
private CustomDialogClass cdd;

//alert dialog for back btn
public void onBackPressed () {
    // Assign to a member instead, not the local variable
    cdd = new CustomDialogClass(Adult1Activity.this);
    cdd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    cdd.show();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (cdd != null) {
        cdd.dismiss();
        cdd = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do it but cdd is exsisting! also i add `AdultActivity.this.onStop` in the MinimizeBTN but nothing happens. you should notice that i use `        moveTaskToBack(true);` for MinimizeBTN. I need this statuse for my Activity and also cdd must dismise too.

Comment: @MinaDahesh do not use onStop() directly. It will be called once you minimise. Are you sure you are assigning cdd member, not the local variable as you were before? In question code I still see you are assigning local cdd in method, not the member.

Comment: i do not understand what you mean... please say it clearly

Comment: @MinaDahesh in `onBackPressed()`, do `cdd = new CustomDialogClass(Adult1Activity.this);`, not `CustomDialogClass cdd = new CustomDialogClass(Adult1Activity.this);`

Comment: oh yes. it's work! Thanks alot! Would you please explain that why i must do that? for example for defining Button, i use `Button btn = ...` but here it's error?

Comment: @MinaDahesh you can define a variable inside a method, if you need it only in a method. This time you needed to reference the created dialog outside a method, so you moved to using member variable. I suggest reading any book for java beginners and a book for Android beginners, you will learn much faster.

Comment: @YaroslovMytkalyk. I have one question, if i want to call notification in MinBTN (use `notificationManager.notify(0, notification);` in MinBTN),how can i pass/update `time` to notification? I do it, but counter is not working/updating.

Comment: @YaroslovMytkalyk. Hi,i need your help. would you please answer this ?http://stackoverflow.com/q/41860396/3671748

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete dialog from activity

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

If you want to delete dialog from that dialog class than use

```
this.dismiss();
```